# Why are images being uploaded at wrong location?

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have a image upload function. I choose a photo from the system and a folder from the dropdown list (basically I have various folders to store images and thumbnails) and upload it. Locally, it works as expected but when I upload it into Godaddy server it is uploading into wrong location on Godaddy server

**My local code for detecting path**

```
$upload_img = cwUpload('fileToUpload','C:\xampp\htdocs\kWebsite\images\K website'."\\".$_POST["path"]."\\",'',TRUE,
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\kWebsite\images\thumbs'."\\".$_POST["path"]."\\",'200','160');
```

**Code for Godaddy server**

```
$upload_img = cwUpload('fileToUpload','\home\gho\public_html\images\K website'."\\".$_POST["path"]."\\",'',TRUE,
    '\home\gho\public_html\images\thumbs'."\\".$_POST["path"]."\\",'200','160');
```

The above code works but it uploads images in the general images folder rather than uploading into desired folder.

Comment: use error reporting and file error handling. Plus the form is unknown.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate on what you mean by form is unknown?

Comment: Quite possibly GoDaddy server are restricted and the upload location is fixed. Once the upload is done, I suggest you try to move to file to the intended location.

Comment: Restricted really? Any reasons if so? But what do you mean by moving files as there are many images.

Comment: Pretty sure the script used here is this one: http://www.codexworld.com/upload-image-create-thumbnail-using-php/

Comment: You are right @veve

Comment: Why was it downvoted? Any particular reason?

Comment: @Nico Just coz I used code online doesn't mean I dont understand code. Understand my question first then kindly comment. You are really out of your mind. I told when the same piece of code is working locally why not on godaddy server. Grow up kid.

Comment: You ask why you are downvoted, I try to reply to you... Grow up, kid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't tell you too much without knowing some examples of path and more examples of things like your restrictions on possible upload directories by your hosting provider.

However, one thing that did make me think this is a problem from your code is that you're defining your path with back slashes (`\`), not forward slashes (`/`), backslashes aren't the proper way to define a file path on *nix systems, as they use forward slashes.

eg: `/path/to/some/file.txt` is valid, however
`\path\to\some\file.txt` is not valid.

Try changing it to use forward slashes and let me know if that worked or helped.

Comment: As a side note, try building your paths like so as described here http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php#113343 using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant for portability purposes.

Comment: @zack I tried with forward slash as well it didn't work. I am not sure if godaddy has any upload restrictions. I don't find any reason of godaddy having such restrictions. Do you know hosting website have such restrictions?

Comment: Can you post the code for your cwUpload method on a github gist and link it here or something?

Comment: Hey @zack6849 I was trying with different path but with backward slash but when I put forward slash I changed the path again. Now I got it. it was forward slash and bit of path too. Thank you. You deserve it.